# Knockout js over mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have developed applications using .net MVC with razor view engine.
Recently I was going through knockoutjs being used for MVC applications.

From a 10000 feet bird's eye view , I see that both the approaches have the similar two way binding mechanism .

In the first approach razor syntax for binding the model and in the second we use the knockout data-bind attributes.

My understanding is , why is it that many people are nowadays preferring Knockout and all the buzz recently . Is there any major advantage of replacing razor syntax over knockout library?

Comment: since it's new year, i think this question is worth a considered appraisal, even tho def an opinionated topic ;)

Comment: @jim tollan At first I thought this question should be closed as too broad, or primarily opinion based. However, I think that the basics can be explained as I've done, and it may be worth for some people to get a quick grip on what's the difference between these technologies. Of course this could be explained in many different ways, and fill a lot of space with explanations, but the basics are the basics, adn not to hard to explain. Perhaps I'll see this Q&A "pass by" or perhaps not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have nothing to do with each other.

### ASP.NET MVC

As its name says, it uses MVC (model view controller) technology. That means that you have a model (all the business logic), that can be used to create view models to render the views (by using the razor template). The browser can post data to the controller, and the controller will usually answer by creating a new view model to render a new view, and send it as response to the browser.

So this technology basically uses the browser to send GET or POST requests to the server, and the server answers with rendered views. It can do it directly, or using AJAX. (ASP.NET MVC is much more versatile and can do much more than rendering views, but this is the basic idea).

So ASP.NET MVC involves the server in all operations: it must instance and use a controller, execute an action and send its result as response to the browser.

## Knockout

This technology is completely different, in several regards:

- it uses MVVM, which consist in a double-way binding between a view (HTML) and a model (JavaScript object). A change in any of the ends is applied automatically on the other end.
- it happens on the client side, without using or depending on server resources (as far as it concerns Knockout)
- it usually doesn't involve heavy business logic, but simple view models that can show and get data from the user.

This is all what Knockout can do for you. If you need to involve the server, and "heavy" business logic, you need to communicate with the server by sending and receiving objects, which you usually do in JSON format by exposing Web API services. (These services are usually implemented with ASP.NET Web API, but can also be implemented with ASP.NET MVC actions with JSON results, which it's a worse option).

### Conclusions

So ASP.NET MVC involves the continuous use of controllers and communication between browser and server, while Knockout is a pure client side technology that doesn't need the server at all. Naturally, to make a Knockout application useful you usually communicate it with the server.

OTOH, Knockout allows to create a Single Page Application, which is a JavaScript application that can run by itself, without loading new full pages from the server, and which usually communicates with services, in the form of Web APIs. One advantage of this is that the application can work even without a server on the other side, and is much more responsive, because it doesn't depend on comminucating with a server to refresh the view.